# using $_GET['VALUE'] from a FORM using method POST

Tags: php

I am troubleshooting CAPTCHA problem in someone Else's code, where the form method is "POST"
But in the action.php file the code is like this:

```
$key=substr($_SESSION['key'],0,5);
$number = $_GET['img_code'];

if($_GET['img_code']){
    if($number==$key)
    {
        echo "done";
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo false;
        exit();
    }
}
```

I have tried to `var_dump($_GET['img_code'])` and as expected I am getting `null` value.

but if I am doing it `var_dump($_POST['img_code'])` I am getting the correct value.

but once I am setting it to POST, I start getting error "captcha not entered correctly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
FORM METHO

`<form action="{$Site_Root}signup.php" method="post" class="frmRegister tutor-registration" name="frmRegister" id="frmRegister" enctype="multipart/form-data" >`

Further Update:

If I am using `$_REQUEST['img_code']` and then doing a `var_dump` I am getting the matching string for $key and $number like 
`string(5) "f065a" string(5) "f065a"`

but problem is when I am applying this as a condition for example:
I am getting -  "captcha not entered correctly."

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
if ($key==$number){                    // condition line is added by me
        if(!empty($_FILES['photo']['name']))
        {
            $_POST['photo'] = fileUpload($_FILES['photo'],TUTOR);
            $thumb->image($physical_path['Tutor'].$_POST['photo']);
            $thumb->size_width(120);
            $thumb->jpeg_quality(100);
            $filename = $thumb->get2(); //small_thumb_
        }
        else
        {
            $_POST['photo'] = "";
        }
        $tutor_id = $tut->Insert($_POST);
        $to_email = $_POST['email'];
        global $mail;
        $mail = '';
        $mail = new htmlMimeMail();
        $mail->setFrom($config[WC_CONTACT_US]);
        //Set Cc
        // $mail->setCc(array($config[WC_CONTACT_US]));
        $mail->setSubject('Welcome to TuitionJobsPortal.com!');
        $tpl2 = new Smarty;
        $tpl2->template_dir = $physical_path['EmailTemplate'];
        $tpl2->compile_dir  = $physical_path['Site_Root']. 'templates_c/';
        $tpl2->debugging    = DEBUG;

        $tpl2->assign(array("membername"    =>  $_POST['tutor_name'],
                            "vcode"         =>  $_POST['verification_code'],
                            "tutor_id"      =>  $tutor_id,
                            "Templates_Image" => $virtual_path['Site_Root'].'templates/images/',
                            "Site_Root" => $virtual_path['Site_Root'],
                          ));

        $content = $tpl2->fetch('registration'. $config['tplEx']);
        $mail->setHtml($content);

        $result = $mail->send(array($to_email));
        header("location: signup.php?signup=true");
        exit();
    }
} //this is added.
```

Comment: Did you change `$_GET` into `$_POST` both where you're setting `$number` and in the `if`-statement? If so, can you `var_dump($number, $key)` to see if they match?

Comment: THen change it to use `$_POST`

Comment: Or perhaps the submit URL used to be `/action.php?img_code=X`?

Comment: Where's the rest of the code ?

Comment: The real questions are: 1) did you leave/logoff? 2) are you expecting a concrete solution for what you posted? Well... you've been given a few answers; see those.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't know what I missed, but I updated to $_REQUEST - now I am getting - `The Captcha wasn't entered correctly. Please try again.`, but I was not getting that error earlier.

Comment: See if anything comes of http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php if you're not checking for possible errors already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can access **$_POST** data from **$_GET** , so either change form method to **GET** or access posted data using `$_POST['img_code']` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$_REQUEST` global variable, it can do the work of both GET and POST,